# Safari displays text after floated element wrong when text has negative top margin

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser, css-float

If text after a floated element has negative margin top Safari displays text over the image instead of on its right side. All other browsers display the text on the right side of element. Is this a bug in Safari?

Demo: https://codepen.io/smohadjer/pen/RLBKGb

HTML

```
<article>
  <h1>Safari's float bug</h1>
  <div class="box">
    container
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</article>
```

CSS

```
article {
  max-width: 400px;
}

div.box {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}

p {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Comment: It's not a bug. But why not give `div.box` a margin-top of 5 px instead of `p` a margin-top of -5 px?

Comment: @ThomasvanBroekhoven If two browsers behave differently, it's not a bug in one of them?

Comment: @MrLister No, they just use different rules to render a page. It's not a bug in Safari, it's a bug in the code.

Comment: @Thomas: Because I don't want elements at the top of a component have space above them otherwise when different components have to appear side by side they won't align horizontally. Note that this is just a reduced test to show the issue.

Comment: It's not two browsers behaving differently, it's one browser against all other browsers! IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc all show the text in the correct location.

Comment: @ThomasvanBroekhoven Negative top margin is not a bug. The OP's code is fine.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the margin from the `p`? This works for me in Safari.